# How to download batch of tracking data for all email sends via rest api

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api

I am a new marketing cloud / rest api developer.  I am confused by all of the terminology in the api documentation and cannot figure out how to accomplish what I think should be a simple thing.

**My ask - I need to download email send performance data for a filtered list of email events**.  E.g. for all email jobs that have occurred during the past 7 days, download a CSV or JSON data set containing columns for hard/soft bounces, clicks and opens, and conversions.

I am using Python, and I have successfully created an app in the App Center, and I've authenticated and downloaded some data via the rest api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry to tell you this, but you will need to [use the SOAP API to gather tracking](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-sdks.meta/mc-sdks/index-sdk.htm).

Fortunately as you are using Python, you can use the [Python SDK](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-sdks.meta/mc-sdks/index-sdk.htm) which can make these calls for you and simplifies the process some. See the [github for more info](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-Python/tree/master/objsamples).

Comment: SOAP not a problem - thanks for the rapid response!  I've got a meeting in 10 minutes and I had nothing but bad news to present - now I've got a path forward!